# GoogleAppEngine log warning

Tags: java, google-app-engine, log4j

I create a default project using GoogleAppEngine for java, and when I deploy my application on google server I have the following warning message for the first request.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (DataNucleus.Connection).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

The log is working fine, but some request are delayed by this problem.

How can I configure it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you sure that this is delaying some of your requests?

GAE does not function like a standard servlet container.  Behind the scenes it unloads any webapps that are idle, and then loads them in again only when it gets a new request for that webapp.  This is basically equivalent to doing a complete redeploy of your application, and it doesn't even begin until *after* GAE has received the request.  Thus any request that triggers a load operation will be noticeably delayed compared to subsequent requests.

But there are a whole lot of things going on that are contributing to the delay, and I think an uninitialized log4j setup is not making much of an actual difference.

Answer (score 0):

This messages means that there is no log4j configuration is found.

You have to put an configuration for log4j, for example into file named as `log4j.properties` in app classpath.

Configuration, for example, would be:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n
```

If your project is Maven based, then the best place to put `log4j.properties` will be `src/main/resources`

Comment: It's not a Maven project, it's a default GoogleAppEngine project.